# Submit POST data without refreshing on a Wordpress site?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have searched the internet a lot for an answer to my question and have not found exactly what I was looking for. So the standard way, from what I have seen, to accomplish this is to use jQuery's submit and AJAX to send the data and redirect to another PHP page. However, I have multiple problems with this. First of all, AJAX. Regular AJAX does not work on Wordpress sites, from what I have seen. How do I get plain old regular AJAX to work? I have not seen a single good tutorial for this that is in plain English for Dummies. Second of all, the PHP redirect. I just want it to send to PHP already on the page. I just want data to go from my Javascript into my PHP already on the page. I don't need a redirect. So, my final question is, can those two problems be fixed in order to do it the traditional way? Or is there a better way to do it that circumvents these problems? I am a complete beginner, BTW- been doing web programming for less than five months. So please, for Dummies or Complete Idiot's language if you can. Here's the form I am submitting from:

```
<form method="post">
Search By File Name: <input type="text" name="searchterms" placeholder="search"></input>
<button type="submit" name="SearchSubmit">Display Results</button>
</form>
```

Here's the PHP I want to execute:

```
$submit=$_POST['SearchSubmit'];
$results=$_POST['searchterms'];
if(isset($submit))
{
//whole bunch of stuff, like sql queries and file generation
}
```

Comment: You can do this with jQuery AJAX. Can you share what you've tried?

Comment: Based on their site, ajax is supported http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX

Comment: Okay, so I have tried tutorials involving adding functions to wordpress, creating plugins, and so on. But I always reach a point in those tutorials where I just don't understand what they are saying! Like this one, for example: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/18/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/

Comment: At what point do you not understand what is happening?

Comment: @mcdonaldjosh Once I get down to the bottom, I'm thinking "Okay... what's the code to put in my webpage to make it work?" What do I add to my webpage to make it work? That's what I don't get. Every plugin has a shortcode or call or something

Comment: btw...if you are redirecting you can set `form_action=""` and put something like `if($_POST)` at the top to handle the form process...its probably slightly quicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 part of code,

HTML where data want to show.

```
 <div id="msg_alert"></div>
```

Jquery for ajax;

```
    $('#msg_form').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    action = 'messaging_post';
    user_id = $('#msg_form #user_id').val(); 
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: ajax_auth_object.ajaxurl,
        data: {
            'action': action,
            'user_id': user_id
        },
        success: function (data) { //alert(data.message);
            if (data.log== true) {
                $('#msg_alert').val(data.message);
            }
            else {
            $('#msg_alert').val('There is an error');
                }
        }
    });

});
```

Third is PHP:

```
add_action('init', 'ajax_review_loading');
function ajax_review_loading() {    
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-auth-script', 'ajax_auth_object', array( 
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'redirecturl' => home_url(),
    'loadingmessage' => __('Sending user info, please wait...')
    ));
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_messaging_post', 'messaging_post' );
}   
function messaging_post(){
    /// Your work here.
    echo json_encode(array('log'=>true, 'message'=> $htm));
    die();
}
```

Comment: almost correct so upvoted, but wordpress uses .noconflict mode so $ should be replaced with the word `jQuery` or assign `$=jQuery', can you change this?

Comment: Thank you! This is just the kind of thing I was looking for! :)

Answer (score 1):

For working you must add **wp_enqueue_script** to ajax_review_loading function

```
add_action('init', 'ajax_review_loading');
function ajax_review_loading() {  

    wp_enqueue_script('ajax-auth-script', get_template_directory_uri() );

    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-auth-script', 'ajax_auth_object', array( 
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'redirecturl' => home_url(),
    'loadingmessage' => __('Sending user info, please wait...')
    ));
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_messaging_post', 'messaging_post' );
}   
function messaging_post(){
    /// Your work here.
    echo json_encode(array('log'=>true, 'message'=> $htm));
    die();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You might need 2 php files, the one that generates the page that you are already seeing, let's call it "my_page.php", and the one that generates the data that you load in that first page without refreshing it, let's call it "livedata.php".

So for example if "my_page.php" generates the following html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function refresh_data(start_at) {
    $("#data_updates_go_here").empty();   // Clear previous contents of the div for refresh
    $.getJSON("livedata.php?start_at=" + start_at,
      function(json_returned) {
         $.each(json_returned, function(key, value){
           $("#data_updates_go_here").append(key + " = " + value + "<br />");
         });
      });
  }
</script>
Data: <br/>
<div id="data_updates_go_here">
</div>
<input type=button onClick="refresh_data(1);" value="Refresh data at 1">
<input type=button onClick="refresh_data(3);" value="Refresh data at 3">
```

You can see that when you load "my_page.php", it won't display any data. inside of the div.

Now "livedata.php" on it's side will have to generate a json structure, as you can see above, it can receive parameters, so you can use them for instance, to limit a query to a database or for any other purposes that you need a parameter to be passed to your php. In the example, "livedata.php" should return a 'json' structure. For instance, your php code could be

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
if ($_REQUEST['start_at'] == 1) {
    echo json_encode(array('value1' => 'data1', 'value2' => 'data2'));
} else if ($_REQUEST['start_at'] == 3) {
    echo json_encode(array('value3' => 'data3', 'value4' => 'data4'));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('value1' => 'data1', 'value2' => 'data2'));
}
?>
```

You can see how you can control the values refreshed by passing a different value for "start_at".

Comment: this actually wont work with wordpress. It will generate a 404 error.